# Android- Registros de SQL mostrar registros con chekbox y botones

Tags: android, sql

Hola tengo registros de sql Android y los muestro en un `listview` con un `adapter`.

```
lst1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lst1);

        //-----------------------------------------------
        //Cargando Registros de la Base de Datos
        AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper( this, "administracion", null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase BaseDeDatos = admin.getWritableDatabase();

        ArrayList<String> ranking = new ArrayList<>();
        String boton="%";

        Cursor fila = BaseDeDatos.rawQuery("select codigo, producto, precio from articulos", null);
        if(fila.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                //diseño de los registros
                ranking.add(fila.getString(0) + boton + fila.getString(1) + " " + fila.getString(2));
            }while(fila.moveToNext());
        }
        BaseDeDatos.close();

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ranking);
        lst1.setAdapter(adapter);
        //-----------------------------------------------
```

de esta forma cargo los registro en un listview pero quiero mostrar en cada registro un chekbox y textview saben como hago para mostrar registros con checkbox y botones.